# Find fake scores in Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I try to find a way to catch fake high scores in Game Center

After gameplay, my app sends the score to Game Center, and also to a server with a hash value.
If the hash value authenticate the score it stores in the database of the server.
This way if the user change the score on the fly when sending to Game Center, I will not find that score in the database, hence I know it is not a valid score

My questions:

1. Does Game Center has some built in mechanism which could do the same (e.g.: sending hash value with the score for authentication)?
2. How can I get the Game Center leaderboard scores of a certain app through HTTP outside iOS, so the server can get the first 100 scores with the corresponding Game Centre playerID and compare it with it's own data?
3. Is there a better approach to find fake scores in Game Center?

Thank You,

Comment: Well the right solution would be for Apple to use certificate pinning on GameCenter requests -- unfortunately this isn't the case today.